# What do I need to cover in my documentation?

Tags: documentation, code-documentation

I'm writing my own documentation for a small ActionScript 3 library that I've written.

I'm trying to keep as close to the layout and content of the Adobe Livedocs as I can, while cleaning it up a little bit.

I think I've covered everything that people will want to know when reading my documentation, but I don't want to miss out on anything crucial before I start adding all of the classes I've created etc.

Is there anything you wish some documentation had? Are there things in most docs that you consider unessential?

Here's what I've got so far: https://projectavian.com/docs/zephyr/#/entity

Some things I've tried to cover are:

1. Easy direct links to documentation sections. ie `/#/class.propertyOrMethod` as above.
2. Neat tables at the top of the page listing briefly each property, method, constant or whatever other relevant staples are present in the class.
3. Clearly separated blocks of information relating to each property or method which can be navigated to directly by the URL in step 1. Clicking the relevant text in the tables at the top of the page will also link down to here.
4. Tidy layout for method arguments with concise explanations about each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the design for the documentation. When I make something for the first time I like to reference other related work to make sure I cover all the same bases. That said, I think you've covered em.

some well documented AS classes that I know:

TweenMax @ http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/TweenMax.html
BulkLoader @ http://media.stimuli.com.br/projects/bulk-loader/docs/
CASA Lib @ http://as3.casalib.org/docs/

You might browse them for inspiration/insight into highly refined Action Script class docs. Each has been through multiple version releases and withstand the test of time.

Comment: The docs for casalib.org are really nice, thanks for that link.